# background extraction using OpenCv

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to extract the background from a video but i don't want to use cv::bgsegm::BackgroundSubtractorMOG,  cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 these methods. because they using frame means. But I planed to use frame comparison method. Where i'm using first frame as background model and i plane to compere pixel values of next frames with first frame pixel values  and if there is no change or change less than threshold it is background pixel. How can implement these using OpenCV and C++

Comment: In my opinion, your question is too vague and shows next to no research efforts. What have you tried? What were the problems you encountered?

Comment: I want to extract the background using pixel comparison of consecutive frames in video

Comment: Markus answer provide all details you need to write your own background subtraction method. If you don't show us [some code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) there's nothing more we can do for you. Just a simple question, however. Why you want a _single difference_ method which will be fairly noisy and inaccurate, and will show you only the silhouettes of moving objects, when you can have for free a MOG based method? Also, don't post other answer on the same topic, but edit your question (there is an _edit_ link under the tags) with the required information.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too vague, I think. I can only give you some hints.

First, your approach is very simplistic. That's not bad. But from my experience, it won't give great results, even if you have a lot of control over your scene. Nevertheless, I do not want to hold you back if you want to make your own experiences.

You probably want to take a look at

- [Operations on Arrays in OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html)
- [Basic Threshold Operations in OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html)

Everything you need should be there. In particular, the `absdiff` operation  and the `threshold` function (with binary threshold type) should be of interest.